# Java Constructor that takes an Array

Tags: java, constructor

How do you create a constructor that takes and array of cards and adds them to a hand which is an arrayList? Below are my 3 constructors so far...

"The class should provide a default constructor(creates an empty hand), a constructor that takes an array of cards and adds them to the hand and a constructor that takes a different hand and add the cards to this hand"

Updated:

```
  public class Hand {

    private List<Hand> hand = new ArrayList<Hand>();

    public Hand(){
        hand = new ArrayList<Hand>();
    }

    public Hand(Card[] cards){
        //this.hand.addAll(Arrays.asList(cards));
        //this.hand = new ArrayList<Hand>(Arrays.asList(cards));]
    }

    public Hand(Hand cards){
         this.hand = Arrays.asList(cards);
    }   
  }
```

Comment: is Hand and Card compatible? what error you getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the list as the instance variable in the `Hand` class:

```
public class Hand {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Hand(Card[] cards) {
        this.cards = Arrays.asList(cards);
    }
}
```

Currently you are declaring a local variable which goes out-of-scope immediately after the constructor returns.

**Update**

It doesn't make sense to have a list of `Hand`s within the `Hand` class itself. IMO, it would be better to let each `Player` keep their own `Hand`.

As far as understand, you want to have a constructor that initializes the list of cards, and a method to add cards to that list. Something as follows:

```
public class Hand {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Hand() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void addCards(Card... cards) {
        this.cards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cards));
    }
}
```

Following are the constructors:

```
public class Hand {
    private List<Card> cards;

    //constructor to create an empty hand
    public Hand() { 
        this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    //constructor to create an empty hand and add all provided cards to it
    public Hand(Card[] cards) {
        this();
        this.cards.addAll(Arrays.asList(cards));
    }

    //constructor to create an empty hand and add all cards in the provided hand
    public Hand(Hand hand) {
        this();
        this.cards.addAll(hand.getCards());
    }
}
```

Comment: he want to add arraylist of cards into arraylist of hands.:)

Comment: @qwertyRocker  How do you create a constructor that takes and array of cards and adds them to a hand which is an arrayList? thats your own question .

Comment: Exactly. How do you create a constructor that takes and ARRAY of cards and adds them to a hand which is an ARRAYLIST?... i thought they were different. No?

Comment: @qwertyRocker you cant add Cards into a list which only accepts Hand unless Cards is a sub type of Hand.

Comment: @qwertyRocker Exactly, please post the exact requirements :)

Comment: No its not a method. I need 3 constructors. "The class should provide a default constructor(creates an empty hand), a constructor that takes an array of cards and adds them to the hand and a constructor that takes a difference hand and add the cards to this hand"... I will now update my code above with what i have tried...

Comment: "The class should provide a default constructor(creates an empty hand)..." That means an empty list of Cards (not an empty list of Hands). You are misunderstanding your requirement, IMHO.

Comment: am i? Oh dear >.< I think i need a break from this for an hour or so. Please check my constructors above, am i heading in the right direction?

Comment: @BheshGurung ithing i dont understand is how can you insert an instance of Cards into a list which only accepts Hand ?? is there an inheritence relationship b/w them ?? or myunderstanding of typed collections is wrong ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: Yes it's not possible and doesn't make sense logically also.

Comment: Does the .getCards HAVE to be implemented in order for the cards to be added if they're passed in a hand?

Comment: It's just a getter method that returns the list of cards in the Hand. `public List<Card> getCards() { return this.cards; }` in `Hand`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Hand(Card[] cards){
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(Arrays.asList(cards));
}
```

Comment: hand should be declared outside of constructor

Comment: Netbeans flags it with: > expected

illegal start of expression

wrong number of type arguments; required 1
----
Thats why i didn't use this way originally :(

Comment: @TomLarkworthy Netbeans says this when i implement your code "no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<Card>)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Hand>) is not applicable
      (actual argument List<Card> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Hand> by method invocation conversion)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
      (actual argument List<Card> cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)"

Comment: @TomLarkworthy he wants to add ArrayList of Cards in ArrayList of Hand.:)

Comment: @qwertyRocker you cant add Cards into a list which only accepts Hand unless Cards is a sub type of Hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Arrays

```
List<Card> hand = Arrays.asList(cards);
```